# Collation with Least Amount of Characters *Necessary* for Hashed Passwords

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, collation

I'm trying to figure out the collation I should use for simple `user` tables that only contain two columns, `email` and `password`, whereby the input for `password` will be the output of `password_hash($str, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)`.

What is the lightest weighted collation necessary for password_hash? Is it `ascii_bin`? `latin1_bin`?

Comment: Measure them and find out?

Comment: @bishop how so?

Comment: Create one table with each collation, then run either synthetic tests to measure select performance with your queries or - if you have it - run your performance test suite to measure change. My guess is that, unless you're doing something like John the Ripper style hash checks, it's not going to matter much.

Comment: Also, unless I'm missing something, if these are hash values then I'd suggest using a `VARBINARY` column, since you're not going to get multibyte out of `password_hash` and you don't really care about collation.

Comment: @bishop pretty much all of what you're talking about is over my head. i'm a beginner when it comes to MySQL. can you elaborate??

Comment: Sure. Please `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table in question. Also, how are you using this table? For authentication purposes in a password-based web-app, or are you building rainbow tables for cracking passwords?

Comment: If you are asking about performance, don't worry -- the differences will be insignificant.

Comment: @RickJames it's funny: every time i ask a question about MySQL, everybody says "don't worry about the perf". the first question i asked about data types, people told me not worry. the effect data types have on perf are insignificant and that collation has a bigger effect. now i ask about collation and i have ppl telling me not to worry lol. im still curious nonetheless, which character set has the least amount of characters to satisfy the output of `password_hash($str, password_default)`?? any idea?

Comment: @bishop `email primary varchar(255) password varchar(255)`. im not creating rainbow tables. just authentication. youre the only person on all of SO that ive seen mention rainbow tables n cracking etc lol. i used to mess around with that stuff ages ago

Comment: Sorry, @Anthony - I usually look through the literal question (about collations) to fish for the 'real' question (about performance).  With sufficient prodding, you can get me to answer the literal question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collation performance...

`..._bin` has the least to do, so they are the fastest.
`ascii_...` checks to see if you are using only 7 bits; so quite fast.
`..._general_ci` checks only bytes, no combinations of bytes.  Example:  German `ß` <> 'ss', unlike most other collations.
`utf8_...` and `utf8mb4_...` check the bytes for valid encodings.

Meanwhile, MySQL 8.0 has made the `utf8mb4_...` collations "orders of magnitude faster" than 5.7.

But I usually find that *other* considerations are more important in any operation in MySQL.

Another example of that...  `SELECT ... function(foo) ...` -- The cost of evaluating the function is usually insignificant relative to the cost of fetching the row.  So, I focus on how to optimize fetching the row(s).

As for hashes, ... It depends on whether the function returns a hexadecimal string or a bunch of bytes...

- Hex:  Use `CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATION ascii_bin (or ascii_ci)`  The `...ci` will do case folding, thereby be more forgiving; this is probably the 'right' collation for the case.
- Bytes:  Use the datatype `BINARY`; which is roughly equivalent to `CHAR CHARACTER SET binary`.

As for whether to use `BINARY` versus `VARBINARY` or `CHAR` versus `VARCHAR`, that should be controlled by whether the function returns a fixed length result.  For example:

`MD5('asdfb') --> '23c42e11237c24b5b4e01513916dab4a'` returns exactly 32 hex bytes, so `CHAR(32) COLLATION ascii_ci` is 'best'.

But, you can save space by using `BINARY(16)` (no collation) and put `UNHEX(MD5('asdfb'))` into it.

`UUID() --> '161b6a10-e17f-11e8-bcc6-80fa5b3669ce'`, which has some dashes to get rid of.  Otherwise, it is `CHAR(36)` or `BINARY(16)`.

Comment: *"The cost of evaluating the function is usually insignificant relative to the cost of fetching the row."* great point!!! im going to wait to see if the other buddy has anything to say, otherwise ill mark this as the answer. from some other comment i read elsewhere on SO recently, ive been under the impression that the time it took to evaluate the row values of columns was based on how big the collation character sets were. for example, its been suggested numerous times all over SO to use ascii_bin for plain alphanumeric strings

Comment: @Anthony I'd only add you might want `VARBINARY(255)` instead of `VARCHAR`. Also check out [Rick's docs on MySQL](http://mysql.rjweb.org/) - super informative.

Comment: @Anthony - I added some hash examples.

Comment: `(255)` has a few minor inefficiencies relative to picking a sensible length.  `CHAR(..)` is slightly better than `VARCHAR(..)` _if_ the length is constant.  That seems to happen only with ascii text in sort length (36 is the longest I can think of).

Comment: The length is not permanently fixed: the output from `password_hash` is an opaque identifier of arbitrary length. The PHP docs suggest using 255. I find that overkill in practice (current lengths are on the order of 60-80 bytes), but it's not unreasonable to ask for more esp. on small tables where the whole rows going to be together (no off page storage).

Comment: the hash info is very interesting. thanks for that. here is an example of the hashing output: `$2y$10$/p0XhJTdSe0OkHDuB3wAduWIhs9fBiKoJS4U8pFRuP2uZkM/7TYjy`. obviously not hex. i believe the hashing output is always 60 characters, so i could use `char(60)`, but i kind of want to keep `varchar(255)` in case PHP randomly changes the the default hashing method one day. im just wondering whether or not `ascii_bin` character set is sufficient for output like that, which i believe it is?

Comment: @bishop - Then `VARCHAR(255)` is justified.

Comment: @Anthony - `CHARACTER SET ascii` looks appropriate.  `COLLATE ascii_bin` is the 'correct' collation since this is clearly case-sensitive.  (latin1/latin1_bin would work, with virtually the same speed; utf8/utf8_bin would be same size, but a tiny slower.  `VARBINARY(255)` is also reasonable, and a tiny bit faster -- after all it is 'opaque'.)

Comment: Yeah, I'd toss in hat for `VARBINARY` -- I use `VARBINARY(128)` generally.

Comment: so `varbinary(255)` is faster than `varchar(255)`? would i have to convert the values to binary in php before inserting? wouldn't converting a string of characters to binary become even more characters?

Comment: rick, would it be possible to get your email address? after reading your guide i still have a few questions about partitions since partitions are new to me, and it would be a great help

Comment: @Anthony - "binary", in this context, is simply "store the bytes unchecked and unchanged".  "char" implies checking the encoding (not all 8-bit bytes are valid for 'ascii' or 'utf8'.  Since the character set used in that hash is a subset of ascii, latin1, and utf8, there is a tiny bit of extra effort when storing into a varchar of one of those character sets.  The vote is in favor of `VARBINARY(255)`, but only by a slight margin.

Comment: okay, thanks. so then a `255` length is sufficient to store the bytes of a string that has a character length of 60! can i ask you a few questions about partitioning in chat?

Comment: @Anthony - 255 vs 60: only minor differences.  Sure start a chat room.  (I never remember how to do such.)

Comment: i'm not exactly sure how to start a chat either lol. ive looked online and its confusing af

Comment: k i finally figured it out. invited u to a chat

Comment: Hmmm...  Now to find the invite.